# Sending files to a queue RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, nservicebus, zeromq

We have a need to persist the files in a queue. We are trying to expore RabbitMQ as a middle layer.  It looks like RabbitMQ doesn't support file streaming. The file size is about less than 10MB. Our client doesn't want to save the files in Disk because of security. What options do I have? Thanks for any suggestions. Are there any other open source tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you convert the files to a byte array then you could persist them in a queue.  If you have a lot of files I imagine it will take a reasonable amount of memory, but it is possible.

Comment: Could you please let me know if there are any examples to stream files?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking me. As I said in my answer you need to convert the file to a byte array and then you can send it to RabbitMQ no problem.  I am not familiar enough with C# to give you the details of creating a byte array from and object, but it should be covered in basic IO